# How can I change my xpath dynamically in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, dynamic, xpath

In my application `id` is changing dynamically,and name is not given to all elements.

Now I want to apply dynamic way of searching `"x path"` in different Division in HTML.
Whenever I refresh page , database value can be added or removed from page.

So is there any way for taking dynamic path of one element??

Comment: You'll have to share some example HTML source for 2 different instances: "first time I get this, the next time I get this", and we can maybe propose an XPath based on some other surrounding non-variable elements (a paragraph header, a position, some label etc.)

Comment: Have you tried the documentation? http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/appendix_locating_techniques.jsp Is any of that not working for you? Do you have specific code examples that you are having problems with?

Comment: Care to share some HTML code?

Comment: 1) do not rely on dynamic id's 2) show us your HTML

Comment: Actually code is so much complex and long.Assume a Div that add its height dynamically and changes Xpath. So I need this approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use custom XPath or CSSPath.
This path have some condition like "OR", "AND", etc.
You can also use some functions like contains(), text(), not(), etc.

References :
http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp